# How to get profile image from Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am implementing Microsoft Azure Active Directory authentication using Microsoft Graph and OAuth2 using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps&tutorial-step=3).

Here is my call which fetches me the displayName, givenName, surName, mail, etc.

```
$graph  = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken->getToken());

$user   = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me?$select=displayName,givenName,surName,mail,mailboxSettings,userPrincipalName') 
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();

$fname  = $user->getGivenName();
$mail   = $user->getMail();
```

Now using the same call, how can I fetch profile image of the user? I don't want to make a separate API call, but want to fetch the photo in same call.

How can I get the profile image?

Answer (score 1):

You cant get users profile image from AAD id token.

The best way of getting the picture is through MS Graph.

In MS Graph API, you can use the below endpoint to fetch photo from Azure AD:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value`

To get this, you need to set the app permission as

> To Get profile picture you need at least one of the following
> permissions `User.ReadBasic.All; User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All`

**C# code sample:**

```
public static async Task<System.Drawing.Image> GetMePhotoAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // GET /me
                Stream photoresponse = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();

                if (photoresponse != null)
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    photoresponse.CopyTo(ms);
                    System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

                    return i;
                }
                else
                { return null; }
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting signed-in user profilephoto: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**Reference:**

[Azure AD Get photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get)

Answer (score 0):

Upon your code in the question, I searched for the Microsoft document and found no way to get profile image by using the same call you provided. And according to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters), we can find that the api of 'List user' can just providing these properties. To prove this conclusion, I also read the document about [creating user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [updating user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), they all showed that profile image is not supported by this api.

For how to get profile image via api, @Hari Krishna has provided solution and document.

[image]